# LVM_INSERTITEM very slow in vista/W7

Tags: c++, listview, windows-vista

in a large listview control collection (say 5000 items), adding a SINGLE extra
item can take 10+ seconds in windows vista/7, and that's just the LVM_INSERTITEM
message handling

it looks that it only affects LVS_ICON, LVS_REPORT and LVS_LIST are still very
fast

can anybody confirm this?

the same code on windows XP with similar listview window styles adds an extra
item instantly

thanks
nikos

Answer (score 1):

No repro on Win7.  Adding 5000 items takes forever, adding one is quick.  Are you sure it isn't the image list that's slow?

Diagnose this by setting up Windows debugging symbols and using Debug + Break All.  Check out the call stack for a pattern.  Post what you see in your question if you need help interpreting it.

Comment: did you try the large icon view? It only happens for that dispay mode, not list or report view

I have tracked this down to the LVM_INSERTITEM message handling. That's where all the delay is. How can I single step inside that message handling, even if I have the windows debug symbols?

Comment: Yes, large icon view (LVS_ICON).

Answer (score 0):

If you've got that much data, consider using a [virtual ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774735(VS.85).aspx#Virtual_ListView_Style)

Comment: I don't think this will help; if it was memory related then all display modes would be slow, now it is only large icon view (!)